# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when using angular2 profile

Tags: angular, grails, grails-plugin

This is my first time using Angular 2 (I've used Angular 1.4 before), and I'm trying to setup a basic Grails app with Angular 2 support. I've followed the [online guide](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/webServices.html#angular2Profile), and ran the following commands:

```
grails create-app my-app --profile angular2
cd my-app
./gradlew bootRun --parallel
```

After running the second (twice, the first time installs a lot of node packages), I get the following output containing the error message:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:client:nodeSetup SKIPPED
:server:compileJava
:client:npmSetup SKIPPED
:client:npmInstall
:server:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:server:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:server:buildProperties UP-TO-DATE
:server:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:server:classes UP-TO-DATE
:server:findMainClass
:server:bootRun
:client:npmInstall UP-TO-DATE
:client:bootRun

> my-app@0.0.0 start /home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client
> ng serve

Unexpected token {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-typescript.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-config.js:2:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/build-webpack.js:6:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/build.js:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Class.module.exports.includedCommands (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/index.js:21:16)
    at /home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:392:61
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Project.addonCommands (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:391:15)
    at Project.eachAddonCommand (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:426:30)
    at module.exports (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:33:13)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:34:26)
    at tryCatch (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
    at invokeCallback (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
    at publish (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:521:7)
    at flush (/home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2373:5)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng serve
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/chris13524/programming/my-app/client/npm-debug.log
:client:bootRun FAILED
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
> Building 90%
```

Here's `npm-debug.log`: https://gist.github.com/chris13524/e5a2d9ea904e4a41f5c339d2b3eb9235

It hangs at the building stage and I have yet to see it complete. `http://localhost:8080` just prints a JSON response.

I'm running on Ubuntu and installed these packages: `node.js npm`. I also installed the `angular-cli` npm package: `sudo npm install -g angular-cli`

I'm not sure how to proceed, should I submit a bug report/issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue. For me, I was using a version of node which didn't have ES6 support. This looks to me like destructing syntax trying to be used for an import.

Comment: I had to update Node (Ubuntu was keeping it back): https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version#480642